# Angular - How do i add more chronometers with different functionality on add chronomoter button click

Tags: angular, angular-material, chronometer

i´m developing a part of a chronometer that measure times of different processes with angular 8 (angular material) in frontend and .net core for the backend.
I devoloped the chronometer that saves in the process and other data, but the requirement says that the system must measures many processes at the same time if the user want to. 
I added a button to add another process and a chronometer, but here starts my question: ¿i have to create another another functions, variables and data of the same kind of that i created before? ¿what about the html?
¿how could do this automatically?

Sorry for my bad english, and for the answer, i am a really new in this.

This is my html:

```
   <mat-grid-tile [rowspan]="1" [colspan]="1">
       <mat-form-field [ngClass]="{'disabledButton': class==true}">
           <mat-label>Transformador</mat-label>
           <mat-select [(value)]="transfo" (selectionChange)="select(transfo)">
               <mat-option *ngFor="let g of comboTransfo" [value]="g" style="width:100%;">
                   {{g.value}}
               </mat-option>
           </mat-select>
       </mat-form-field>
   </mat-grid-tile>
   <mat-grid-tile [rowspan]="1" [colspan]="1">
       <button mat-fab color="primary" *ngIf="play" (click)="start()" >
           <mat-icon>play_arrow</mat-icon>
       </button>
       <button mat-fab color="primary" *ngIf="isPause" (click)="pause()" >
           <mat-icon>pause</mat-icon>
       </button>
       <button mat-fab color="primary" *ngIf="isStop" (click)="stop()" >
           <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
       </button>
   </mat-grid-tile>
   <mat-grid-tile [rowspan]="1" [colspan]="1">     
       <mat-form-field [ngClass]="{'disabledButton': class==true}">
           <mat-label>Proceso</mat-label>
               <mat-select [(value)]="proceso">
               <mat-option *ngFor="let f of comboTipoEtapa" [value]="f" >
                   {{f.value}}
               </mat-option>
           </mat-select>
       </mat-form-field>
   </mat-grid-tile>
   <mat-grid-tile [rowspan]="1" [colspan]="1">
       <mat-card>
           <mat-card-header>
               <mat-card-title>Tiempo</mat-card-title>
           </mat-card-header>
           <mat-card-content>
               <div></div>
               <div>{{now}}</div>
               <div>{{contador.dias+ " dias " + +contador.horas + " Hs. "+ contador.minutos+ " min. " + contador.segundos+" seg."}}</div>
           </mat-card-content>
       </mat-card>
   </mat-grid-tile>
   <mat-grid-tile [rowspan]="1" [colspan]="1">
       <mat-form-field [ngClass]="{'disabledButton': class==true}">
       <mat-label>Empleado</mat-label>
           <mat-select [(value)]="empleado">
               <mat-option *ngFor="let g of comboEmpleados" [value]="g" >
                   {{g.value}}
               </mat-option>
           </mat-select>
       </mat-form-field>
   </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
<br>
<button mat-raised-button mat-fab color="primary" (click)="addProceso()" matTooltip="agregar proceso" >
   <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
</button>
```

This is a part of my ts:

```
start(){

    if((this.proceso && this.empleado && this.transfo) != undefined){
      this.play=!this.play;
      this.isPause=!this.isPause;
      this.isStop=true;
      this.class=true;
      this.mensajeSnack=`Proceso iniciado`
      this.openSnackBar(this.mensajeSnack);
      this.id=setInterval(()=>{

        this.contador=this.contadorPausado;
        if(this.play==false){
          this.contador.segundos++;
          if(this.contador.segundos>60){
            this.contador.segundos=0;
            this.contador.minutos++;
          }
          if(this.contador.minutos>60){
            this.contador.segundos=0;
            this.contador.minutos=0;
            this.contador.horas++;
          }
          if(this.contador.horas>24){
            this.contador.segundos=0;
            this.contador.minutos=0;
            this.contador.horas=0;
            this.contador.dias++;
          }
        }
      },1000)

      if(this.comienzo==true){
        this.getFechaInicio=new Date();
        this.dataEtapa=new Etapa();
        this.dataEtapa.idTipoEtapa=this.proceso.id;
        this.dataEtapa.idEmpleado=this.empleado.id;
        this.dataEtapa.idTransfo=this.transfo.id;
        this.dataEtapa.dateIni=this.getFechaInicio;

        this.etapaService.addEtapa(this.dataEtapa).subscribe(
          (res) => {
            console.log(res.idEtapa);
            let idEtapa=res.idEtapa;
            this.dataEtapa.idEtapa=idEtapa;
                this.isLoadingResults = false;
          },
          err => {
            console.log(err);
            this.isLoadingResults = false;
          }
        );

        this.comienzo=false;

      }

    }
}

addProceso(){

  }
```

Comment: did you try ng for ?

Comment: but i don't know how many chronometers want to add the user

Comment: and if i could a ngFor, what happen with the variables that i used in the first chronometer? that variables would be in use

Comment: Any idea of how to do this?. I deleted my own chronometer and import de easyTimer.js library. But i still without know how to add the html template

Comment: Will you please rephrase the question??

Comment: "repeat" the html part, every time that a user press the button

Comment: well i need to write a big answer for it..give me a moment

Comment: yes, there is no problem for me to wait :)

Comment: if you can create stackblitz of your chronometer project?? that would ease the things

Comment: give me a moment

Comment: This is the part of all the projects...it has an error, but i couldn't figure out what is
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b1j8kg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: i meant that was a part of all the project

Comment: Yea bro I'm looking into it